# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1436 Thread stack overrun on Shared Hosting

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel

Hi I'm using this Laravel Package https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

This is my code:

```php
$RelatedProducts = Product::where('product_status', 1)
            ->search($product->product_name)
            ->with('images')
            ->take(10)->get();
```

Its working fine on my Local Machine (XAMPP-Windows) but not on my Linux Shared Hosting

When I'm searching for something big it returning this error:

I think I have to change the SQL config file, but on shared hosting they won't allow it, is there any other way to do this?

```sql
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1436 Thread stack overrun: 230160 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and 32000 bytes needed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

You should raise the thread_stack to 512k, which is usually enough to avoid this problem permanently.

1. Backup and Edit my.cnf, locate thread_stack directive and modify to 512k
2. Restart MySQL service to reload new configuration
3. Run your PHP script or test again

for more information : [Mysql bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74985)